# Match Document Key Nearest to Search Value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "Stats1",
    "minutes" : {
        "0" : [
            {
                "0" : {
                    "f" : 1,
                    "t" : 0,
                    "v" : "0"
                }
            }
        ],
        "22" : [
            {
                "2" : "1"
            }
        ],
        "29" : [
            {
                "32" : "2"
            }
        ],
        "38" : [
            {
                "40" : "3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and when i try:

```
 db.stats.aggregate()
  .project({"_id":"1", "minArray": {"$objectToArray": "$minutes"}})
```

i am getting error message:

"$objectToArray requires a document input, found: array"

and when i try:

```
 db.stats.aggregate()
  .project({"_id":"1", "minArray": {"$arrayToObject": "$minutes"}})
```

i am getting error message:

"$arrayToObject requires an array input, found: object"

[image]

I would like to get closest value for minute exact or lower than 30:

```
{ "minute" : "29", "value" : [{ "32" : "2"}] }
```

Comment: As per the message says, The `$objectToArray` expects a document `{}` as input to the operator, But you provided an Array as input.

Comment: You're edits are not telling us anything. As already noted, the error is expected since this is not valid input for `$objectToArray`, What are you expecting to happen? It would be useful if you actually showed your expected output.

Comment: @NeilLunn Why "minutes" are not valid object input?

Comment: The errors basically mean there are other documents in the collection that don't share the same data type. If you `$match` for the specific `_id` it will be fine, but you need to look at the rest of your collection and see where those are wrong.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanx, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the errors are because without a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) your pipeline is attempting to access other documents which don't have the expected structure. That's really something separate to sort out though.

To actually answer your question from it's end objective, you want a pipeline like this:

```
var _id = "Stats1";
var target = 30;

db.stats.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id" : _id } },
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "working": { 
            "$map": {
              "input": { "$objectToArray": "$minutes" },
              "in": {
                "k": { "$toInt": "$$this.k" },
                "v": "$$this.v",
                "diff": { "$abs": { "$subtract": [ target, { "$toInt": "$$this.k" }] } }
              }         
            }
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$arrayToObject": {
            "$map": {
              "input": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": {
                    "$objectToArray": {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$$working",
                        { "$indexOfArray": [ "$$working.diff", { "$min": "$$working.diff" } ] }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this.k", "diff" ] }
                }
              },
              "in": {
                "k": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$$this.k", "k"] }, "minute", "value" ] },
                "v": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$$this.k", "k"] }, { "$toString": "$$this.v" }, "$$this.v" ] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which of course returns the wanted output:

```
{ "minute" : "29", "value" : [ { "32" : "2" } ] }
```

In sequence you do the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) as you initially attempted, but then you need that *key* or `"k"` value to actually be converted to numeric for comparison. You also need to calculate the *difference* of that from the value you are searching for, in this case `30`. That gives you a "working" copy of the data in array form, which is important for the next input stages.

The next section is basically read inwards from the levels of indentation to best understand the order.

First you basically want to extract the element from that working array where the *difference* ( using `$abs` so positive and negative are the same ) is the minimal value with `$min`. This gives the position of the first match from [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) and used that with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to return that single selected element from the working array.

We don't want all the fields in that object, so [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) converts that single object into `"k"` and `"v"` paired objects, and the first step is to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) where that *key* is the *difference* field and remove this from that list.

Next you want to rename the fields and change some data formats, so the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) iterates the remaining array ( just two entries ) assigning readable names and setting the string format for the `"minute"`.

Finally this can go back to an object as [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) as the final output. Since we wanted to refer to that `"working"` array several times, we declare in [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) which allows us to do that. And since all of that was an expression that outputs what you want as a document, you use [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to wrap this as an "expression" is basically it's single expected argument.